# Loading images from asset catalog from private pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4.1

I have created a private pod which has some images, i have put that images in asset catalog, now when i try to access it, it does not load in my host app where i have installed this private pod

This is my private podspec

```
s.resource_bundles = {
     'myPod' => ['myPod/Assets/*.xcassets']
  }
```

and i have added this asset catalog in the Assets folder which gets created with pod

This in my VC inside `viewDidLoad` in my private pod

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "myIcon", in:Bundle(for:myVC.self), compatibleWith: nil) {
    sendButton.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    sendButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
}
```

I can also see that assets file in my host app, pods section inside Resources folder, also my bundle is not nil.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, i found a solution, turns out the problem is with resource bundles, I can see `Assets.car` present in bundle, but images were still not loading.

I thought using png files might work, and i can see that it was being copied to the bundle but i can't access it with image name, turns out i have to add this to image name `myPod.bundle/imageName` and it worked but still it was not a good solution.

Finally there was a cleaner and much simpler solution for this, is to use `resources` instead of `resource_bundles` in pod spec file, just thats it.

```
s.resources = 'myPod/Assets/**'
```

then do pod install and it will load images from your asset catalog.